# 2008 Toyota Highlander Hybrid leaking at transmission seal -

Tags: toyota, hybrid, highlander

Our 2008 Toyota Highlander Hybrid has a leak that the local Toyota dealer (in Spokane) says is at the silicone transmission seal.   The shop manager indicated that they have never seen this before and don't get many Hybrids in.  The car is about 10 years old.  Some part of me says, I should probably call the Toyota dealer in Seattle because they probably see tons of Hybrids.  Is it rare for a transmission leak to show up in a Hybrid?  It seems like it should be just as common as a regular car.  Any recommendations on where to take the car to be looked at?

Comment: Maybe they don't see many hybrids, with or without a transmission seal leak. If they don't see many hybrids, they surely don't see many with a seal leak like yours. What are you really trying to see? If they know what's going on with your car? Realistically, they have trained technicians who can diagnose an issue, whether they see hybrids much or not. We here on MVM&R do it every day without even *seeing* the car. Is there some reason you do not trust their diagnosis?

Comment: I should have added more detail.  I believe it is a transmission leak.  The Toyota Dealership in Spokane, has indicated that they aren't sure HOW to fix this relative to the Hybrid model.  There should be a Toyota repair document or something that should cover the topic, so it seems a little odd that they are indicating that they don't know "what" to do.  Many times a mechanic will try and fix a problem, even if they don't know what it is, and happily charge you for it.  In this case, they aren't even referring us to another dealership or shop.  Maybe hybrid transmission leaks are really rare.

Comment: When a vehicle comes out of the factory, it's just like you suggest: there's a service manual which covers *everything* ... and then it covers it down to the littlest detail and is step-by-step. At this point, yes, you might want to talk to someone in Seattle and see if they can help you. If the leak isn't too big (drip, drip, drip), you may be able to drive it to Seattle to get fixed, but you'd be at the mercy of their shop and how long it takes for them to fix it. Great fun.